# Why does DOMDocument::saveHTML()'s behavior differ in encoding UTF-8 as entities in style & script elements?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, html-entities

Given a `DOMDocument` constructed with a stylesheet that contains an emoji character, I've found some strange behavior when serializing the DOM back out to HTML.

```php
$html = <<< HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <style>span::before{ content: "⚡️"; }</style>
</head>
<body>
  <span></span>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The result of `$dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement)` is (as desired):

```html
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<style>span::before{ content: "⚡️"; }</style>
</head><body><span></span></body></html>
```

But `$dom->saveHTML()` returns (erroneously):

```html
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<style>span::before{ content: "&#9889;&#65039;"; }</style>
</head><body><span></span></body></html>
```

Notice how the emoji “⚡️” is encoded as the HTML entities `&#9889;&#65039;` inside of the stylesheet. It is treated as a literal string since CSS escape `\26A1` should be used instead.

I tried setting `$dom->substituteEntities = false` but without any effect.

The same HTML entity conversion is also happening inside of `<script>` elements, which causes similar problems in browsers.

Test via online PHP shell: https://3v4l.org/jMfDd

Comment: One piece to the puzzle is that libxml doesn't seem to recognize `<meta charset="utf-8">`. If I replace it with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` then the entity encoding is not performed. However, this still doesn't explain why the behavior differs between `$dom->saveHTML()` and `$dom->saveHTML( $dom->documentElement )`.

Comment: If you provide a node the result is a serialized fragment, not a whole document. That might be a reason for the different behavior.

Comment: I have [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59940487/1255289) for what's happening here. I can only guess at _why_ it's happening though.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the encoding before loading the HTML with emojis on DOMDocument:

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($htmlCode, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

EDIT: As mention by post owner, mb_convert_enconding is deprecated in future PHP versions (currently tested on 8.2.5 and works fine). For later versions of PHP take a look at https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mbstring-qprint-base64-uuencode-html-entities-deprecated#html

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: https://3v4l.org/KZLZi I also get a notice: `Deprecated: mb_convert_encoding(): Handling HTML entities via mbstring is deprecated; use htmlspecialchars, htmlentities, or mb_encode_numericentity/mb_decode_numericentity instead`. Again, the goal is to _retain_ the emoji in the output, not convert to entities.

Comment: @WestonRuter Updated answer based on your comment, I'm currently using this on production server on PHP 8.2.5, thanks for pointing the deprecation, it will be on my consideration for updates

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't seem the answer gets me the desired result. The goal is to have _no_ entities in the output.